# Deuteronomy 12:15 "In all thy gates"

Tags: deuteronomy

"Notwithstanding thou mayest kill and eat flesh in all thy gates"

We know that this got rid of the restriction of slaughtering animals only in front of the temple, but what about the "thy gates" part?

Doesn't that mean that the restriction was only lifted for gated towns, what about people living outside of the gated cities?

The verse says nothing about allowing slaughter of animals outside of "gates" (towns).

The interlinear is consistent, the word  šə·‘ā·re·ḵā for "gates" always refers to towns, never to houses outside of towns.

So was it still banned to slaughter animals outside of city gates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that "in all your gates" is an expression meaning "everywhere you live". A part of the community home taken to represent the whole. For safety reasons, houses outside a community of some kind would be comparatively rare (and even those might have gates of their own). We may compare "the stranger within thy gates" (ch14 v21), "the Levite within thy gates" (ch14 v27), "the widow within thy gates" (ch14 v29), where there is no obvious reason to suppose a town/countryside difference.

The distinction is being made in this chapter between killing animals for burnt offering and killing animals for ordinary meals. vv1-4 show that the sacrificial locations of the native gods of the land are not to be used, and must be destroyed. vv5-14 make it clear that burnt offerings and other sacrifices are to be made "at the place which the Lord will choose" (which means Jerusalem, in the context of Deuteronomy).

The point of v15 is that this restriction "to one place" is lifted if the meal is not a sacrificial one. Provided you make sure that the blood is reserved for the Lord, and provided you restrict yourself to "clean" animals, herded or hunted, you can be a carnivore in any part of the country.